# how to display ruby output in browser?

Tags: html, ruby

Am learning ruby scripting language. I was implementing exercises in ruby. 
In that I had a one problem. I need to display the ruby output in browser.

For example, I have a one ruby script, named hello.rb. It will print the "Hello world message". Normally if we execute this with ruby interpreter it will print that in the terminal. I need to print that hello world message in the browser by invoking the ruby script.

For that I was referred in the internet. In that they told that you need to install gem 'tilt'.

Without installing any gems how can we achieve this ?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Without installing any gem, what means without a web framework like Sinatra or Rails you would have to build a http server yourself (see an [example](https://www.practicingruby.com/articles/implementing-an-http-file-server)). That server needs at least to be able to accept requests, run the script, capture the script's output and then render a html document with the output and return it to the browser. This is way too broad
for a stackoverflow question. Perhaps you could start following the linked article and asks more specific questions when you face a problem.

Comment: @spickermann you must be kidding :) even simple `cgi-bin` will do. Any existing web server might execute the external executables and render the output. But this is still too broad for SO question.

Comment: @mudasobwa I read the question as if he wants to use plain Ruby without any gems. And I guess this implies without any other external dependencies (like the need to have web server installed). Would be great if the OP takes to chance to elaborate about the requirements.

Comment: Ruby comes with a simple HTTP server (Webrick, or something like it).  Therefore, a solution is possible using standard Ruby without any gems.  It shouldn't even be very difficult.  I'll try to find another question asking how to do that--if so, this can be a duplicate of that question.  Otherwise, this question should remain open--it's not too broad and easily answerable.

Comment: Discussion about the closure of this question is taking place on [meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/329093/focused-question-with-simple-answer-closed-as-too-broad)

Answer (score 3):

Ruby comes with a simple web server, [webrick](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.1/libdoc/webrick/rdoc/WEBrick.html).  The following code uses *webrick* to implement a simple "hello, world" web server:'

```
require "webrick"

server = WEBrick::HTTPServer.new(Port: 8000)
server.mount_proc "/" do |req, res|
  res.body = "Hello, world!\n"
end
server.start
```

When run, it prints some log output to show that it is running and ready to serve requests:

```
[2016-07-22 12:02:01] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2016-07-22 12:02:01] INFO  ruby 2.3.1 (2016-04-26) [x86_64-linux]
[2016-07-22 12:02:01] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=16318 port=8000
```

I used the *nix utility *curl* to give the server a request:

```
wayne@treebeard:~$ curl localhost:8000
Hello, world!
```

Although I used curl, any web browser would also work.  After starting the program, send your web browser to:

```
http://localhost:8000
```

Comment: Without connecting client how to I display the "hello world" message in web browser ?

Comment: @suresh I do not understand your question.  What does "Without connecting client" mean?

Comment: In here you said something called use curl. That I don't want to do. Like executing a html file, I need to execute the ruby in it display the hello world output in the browser window.

Comment: @suresh curl is a command-line tool for making HTTP requests.  I used it because it was a convenient way to show that the server is HTTP compliant.  Your web browser will also work: Run the program, then send your browser to `http://localhost:3000`

Comment: @suresh I do not understand what you mean.  It appears I did not understand your question.

Comment: If it run the ruby program your given, it does not open the browser window and it does not write the "hello world" output in the browser.

Comment: @Wayne i have found the answer using erb we can do this http://www.stuartellis.eu/articles/erb/